# What kernel size do I have to use when there are 3 channels on Conv2D Keras Layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I've just started to learn CNN with Tensorflow and Keras.

I have found these two implementations, the first is for U-NET and the second one is for VGG-16:

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
```

VGG-16:

```
def vgg16(input_size = (224,224,3)):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=input_size,filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
```

I have notices that on U-NET, they are using one channel images, and VGG-16, they are using three channels images. And also, U-NET Conv2D layer use `kernel_size` equals to 3, and on VGG-16, equals to (3, 3).

Is there any relationship between that with one channel image, they use 1D kernel size, and with three channels image, they use 2D kernel size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U-Net is used for semantic segmentation whereas VGG-16 is used for classification.

[image]

usually, with U-Net we predict a single-channel mask. The input can have 3 channels but for generating binary masks we almost always use signle channel output.

VGG on the other hand just gives a softmax probability for the input image which we use to decide which class an image belongs to.

[image]

Finally, in keras/tensorflow, `kernel_size  = 3` and `kernel_size = (3,3)` is equivalent. For Conv2D, you always need 2-d kernels, when we pass an integer like `3`, keras uses same dimensional kernels meaning the width and height of the kernel is 3.

[image]

So, `kernel_size` has no relations with channels, kernels are related with the spatial dimension (width and height of images/feature maps), number of filters is related with channels.

Relevant papers and code:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4038.pdf (vgg16 segmentation)

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse576/17sp/notes/Sachin_Talk.pdf (encode-decoder architecture)

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.00561.pdf (vgg16 encode-decoder (+skip connections) for segmentation)

https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras

https://github.com/upul/Semantic_Segmentation

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have read some papers where VGG-16 is used to do semantic segmentation.

Comment: yes, in that case you'll need a vgg-16 encoder and a vgg-16 decoder, which is actually a different architecture than the traditional vgg-16 we refer too. As you can see in segmentation task we need to output a 2d same dimension as the input, so we need upscaling, as you can see from the vgg16 it gets narrowed (the feature maps), we need a decoder to upscale the feature maps again to get the right dimensions.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the explanation. Do you know where can I find that architecture with a vgg-16 encoder and a vgg-16 decoder? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can upvote it more. Thanks a lot for your time and support.

Comment: Happy to be helpful, added the relevant papers and github repos.

Comment: I'm trying to find an implementation for the VGG Decoder, but I can't. https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse576/17sp/notes/Sachin_Talk.pdf has what I have to do, but I don't know how to implement the up-sampling. Maybe I can use the UpSampling2D function from Keras. What do you suggest me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use Upsampling2D or/and Conv2DTranspose (compare with max pooling and conv2d in traditional vgg-16) https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose They both will help you get the initial image shape from the reduced feature maps. Usually, the decoder will have the exact opposite flow than the normal vgg16,  the decoder will reconstruct the original image shape (let's say 224 by 224, 3 channels) from a feature shape (7 by 7, 2048 channels/filters.)

Comment: Here's a close implementation you can use: https://github.com/YPDLsegmentation/VGG16-UNet/blob/master/model.py

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are literally saving my life (well, not literally).

Comment: I have asked this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816921/using-conv2dtranspose-to-output-the-double-of-its-input-shape, because I'm getting troubles to understand Conv2DTransponse. It is easier for me use UpSampling2D and Conv2D instead.