# Using Conv2DTranspose to output the double of its input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm newbie with Python 3.7.7 and Tensorflow 2.1.0 and I'm trying to understand [Conv2DTranspose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose). I have tried this code:

```
def vgg16_decoder(input_size = (7, 7, 512)):
    inputs = Input(input_size, name = 'input')

    conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), dilation_rate = 2, name = 'conv1')(inputs)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv1, name = 'vgg-16_decoder')

    opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

And this is its summary:

> ```
> Model: "vgg-16_decoder"
> _________________________________________________________________
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
> =================================================================
> input (InputLayer)           (None, 7, 7, 512)         0
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv1 (Conv2DTranspose)      (None, 9, 9, 512)         1049088
> =================================================================
> Total params: 1,049,088
> Trainable params: 1,049,088
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
> ```

But I want an output of `(None, 14, 14, 512)` from `conv1`.

I have changed filter size to `(3, 3)` and I get this summary:

> ```
> Model: "vgg-16_decoder"
> _________________________________________________________________
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
> =================================================================
> input (InputLayer)           (None, 7, 7, 512)         0
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv1 (Conv2DTranspose)      (None, 11, 11, 512)       2359808
> =================================================================
> Total params: 2,359,808
> Trainable params: 2,359,808
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
> ```

I'm trying to get to this using `Conv2DTranspose`:

```
# A piece of code from U-NET implementation

up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name = 'up6')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp1')(drop5))
```

And its summary:

> ```
> drop5 (Dropout)                 (None, 16, 16, 1024) 0           conv5_2[0][0]
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> upsp1 (UpSampling2D)            (None, 32, 32, 1024) 0           drop5[0][0]
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> up6 (Conv2D)                    (None, 32, 32, 512)  2097664     upsp1[0][0]
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> ```

It upsamples by 2 its input and it changes its number of filters.

How can I do that with Conv2DTranspose?

**UPDATE**:

I think, or I suppose, I did it, but I don't understand what I did:

```
conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), strides = 2, name = 'conv1')(inputs)
```

With the previous statement, I get this summary:

> ```
> Model: "vgg-16_decoder"
> _________________________________________________________________
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
> =================================================================
> input (InputLayer)           (None, 7, 7, 512)         0
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv1 (Conv2DTranspose)      (None, 14, 14, 512)       1049088
> =================================================================
> Total params: 1,049,088
> Trainable params: 1,049,088
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
> ```

If you want to correct me or explain what I have done here, you are welcome.

**UPDATE 2**:

By the way, I'm trying to create an VGG-16 decoder. This is the code for my VGG-16 encoder:

```
def vgg16_encoder(input_size = (224,224,3)):
    inputs = Input(input_size, name = 'input')

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_1')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_2')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_1')(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_1')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_2')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_1')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_2')(conv3)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_3')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_1')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_2')(conv4)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_3')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_4')(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_1')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_2')(conv5)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_3')(conv5)
    pool5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_5')(conv5)

    opt = Adam(lr=0.001)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = pool5, name = 'vgg-16_encoder')

    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we design encoder-decoder architecture we need some operation that reverses the operations already done. So, let's say in encoder we have Conv2D, and Pooling (common in architectures like VGG). We use Conv2dTranspose (this can be thought of reverse operation of Conv2D), and Upsampling2D (reverse operation of Pooling (well, not rigorously [pooling is an irreversible operation as information is lost])).

**N.B: You don't want to upsample your feature maps with Conv2DTranspose (you can but for VGG I don't think Conv2DTranspose will give the upsampled feature maps the way you want in your decoder), it's not designed that way (it also learns upsampling but it learns the best upsampling parameters which is slightly different). You'll end up with really large kernels which will result in a completely different network than the VGG-encoder you're talking about.**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

def encoder_decoder_conv(input_size = (224,224,3)):
    ip = Input((224,224,3))
    # encoder
    conv = Conv2D(512, (3,3))(ip) # look here, the default padding is used
    # decoder
    inv_conv = Conv2DTranspose(3, (3,3))(conv)
    # simple model
    model = Model(ip, inv_conv)
    return model

model1 = encoder_decoder_conv()
model1.summary()

def encoder_decoder_pooling(input_size = (224,224,3)):
    ip = Input((224,224,3))
    # encoder
    pool = MaxPool2D((2,2))(ip) # look here, the default padding is used
    # decoder
    inv_pool = UpSampling2D((2,2))(pool)
    # simple model
    model = Model(ip, inv_pool)
    return model

model2 = encoder_decoder_pooling()
model2.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 222, 222, 512)     14336     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 224, 224, 3)       13827     
=================================================================
Total params: 28,163
Trainable params: 28,163
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 112, 112, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D) (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```

As, you can see in the first model, with Conv2DTranspose we reverse the operations to get exactly the same shape as input (224,224,3).

For model2, we reverse the operation of Pooling (in terms of feature map shape) with Upsampling.

So, as you're trying to make a VGG-decoder, and VGG mostly consists of Conv2D and Maxpooling2D, all you have to do reverse those operations using Conv2dTranspose and Upsampling so you get the exact input shape (224, 224, 3) from the feature map shape (7, 7, 512).

Finally, there are some variations of the decoder part, but I think you're looking for this VGG-16 decoder.

```
def vgg16_decoder(input_size = (7,7,512)):
    inputs = Input(input_size, name = 'input')

    pool5 = UpSampling2D((2,2), name = 'pool_5')(inputs)
    conv5 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_3')(pool5)

    conv5 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_2')(conv5)

    conv5 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_1')(conv5)

    pool4 = UpSampling2D((2,2), name = 'pool_4')(conv5)

    conv4 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_3')(pool4)

    conv4 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_2')(conv4)
    conv4 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_1')(conv4)
    pool3 = UpSampling2D((2,2), name = 'pool_3')(conv4)

    conv3 = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_3')(pool3)
    conv3 = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_2')(conv3)

    conv3 = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_1')(conv3)

    pool2 = UpSampling2D((2,2), name = 'pool_2')(conv3)
    conv2 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_2')(pool2)

    conv2 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_1')(conv2)

    pool1 = UpSampling2D((2,2), name = 'pool_1')(conv2)

    conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_2')(pool1)

    conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(3, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_1')(conv1) # to get 3 channels

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv1, name = 'vgg-16_encoder')

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model = vgg16_decoder()
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "vgg-16_encoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           [(None, 7, 7, 512)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
pool_5 (UpSampling2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_3 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
pool_4 (UpSampling2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_3 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
pool_3 (UpSampling2D)        (None, 56, 56, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_3 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 56, 56, 256)       1179904   
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
pool_2 (UpSampling2D)        (None, 112, 112, 256)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 112, 112, 128)     295040    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
pool_1 (UpSampling2D)        (None, 224, 224, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 224, 224, 64)      73792     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv2DTranspose)    (None, 224, 224, 3)       1731      
=================================================================
Total params: 17,037,059
Trainable params: 17,037,059
Non-trainable params: 0
```

It takes `(7, 7, 512)` feature shape and reconstructs the original image dimension `(224, 224, 3)`.

In summary, the mechanical way of designing a decoder would be going in the opposite direction (relative to the encoder) while doing reverse operations. As for details of Conv2DTranspose and Upsampling2D, if you want to really understand these concepts in more depth:

https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers

https://www.matthewzeiler.com/mattzeiler/deconvolutionalnetworks.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, reading your **N.B.** comment, the idea is to use UpSampling2D and Conv2D to get the decoder, isn't it?

Comment: @VansFannel yes, I also added the implementation of a possible decoder, you can check that.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, but in your decoder implementation you use Conv2DTranspose, this is why I ask you about to use Conv2D. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In N.B I actually mentioned conv2dtranspose, not conv2d for decoder. Technically, you can use Conv2D too in the decoder in your vgg example (as you have used same padding), but for cases where there is valid padding, in those cases Conv2DTranspose will do the trick.

Comment: Conv2DTranspose is used in decoder the same way Conv2D is used in the encoder, Upsampling2D is used in the decoder the same way MaxPooling is used in the encoder - in my implementation here.

Comment: Ok. I have misunderstood your N.B. comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired form you need

```
conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (8, 8), strides = 1, name = 'conv1')(inputs)
```

You may find this post on transposed convolution operation useful https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-convolutions-in-deep-learning-717013397f4d

Comment: It is what they called deconvolution, interesting to see how it might be implemented!

Comment: The post actually talks about the difference between transposed and de-convolution. Essentially, Transposed convolution is a normal convolution where the input was heavily padded in a fancy way. De-convolution is different, it is about finding inverse matrix.

Comment: This is not a general way of doubling the size of the image. It only works in this specific set of parameters. Imagine, if they would like to turn a 128x128 image into a 256x256 one, they would need to use a filter of size 129x129?

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand why `kernel_size` needs to be `(8, 8)` and `strides` is `1`.

Comment: Basically I thought about it as follows:
what integer filter size `f` and stride s I need to have to get `(14 - f)/s + 1= 7`. Since everything has to be integers here only two solutions exit: `f = 8, s = 1` and `f = 2, s = 2`.

Comment: Good to know, I did not find a definition of 'deconvolution' on the Internet. Do you happen to have a source/reference for that ?

Comment: The reference in my reply offers only animation and a point that you can calculate parameters as if it is a inverse of convolution. The detailed maths in described here:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285v1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

`conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), strides = 2, name = 'conv1')(inputs)` works because you are using a stride of 2. In a normal convolution, this would mean applying the filter only every two steps (skipping one step every time), which would result in an output half the size of the input. However, in a transposed convolution things are essentially reversed, and a stride of 2 gives you double the output size. It does this by basically inserting holes into the input before applying the convolution.

The first snippet (`conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), dilation_rate = 2, name = 'conv1')(inputs)`) doesn't work because you were specifying a *dilation* of 2, not a stride. This is completely different. Dilation inserts "holes" into your *filter*, e.g. a filter that looks like [x1 x2 x3] becomes [x1 0 x2 0 x3] with a dilation of 2. However, this filter-with-holes is then applied as normal on the input.

Why does the output size change even when using `dilation`? This is due to padding. Normally, the output of a convolution will be smaller if no padding is done. In a transposed convolution, it will be larger instead. You can avoid this by using `padding=same`.

tl;dr: You can double your image size by using `Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, filter_size, strides = 2, padding="same")`.